# javascript re-populate an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am using:

```
var myArry = [];
```

as a global variable. I then populate the array with some data from the database.
If I then want to replace the array data with new data do I have to empty / reset the original array.

Or what is the correct method?

Answer (score 4):

Here are some ways to empty an array:

```
myArray = [];
myArray = new Array();
myArray.length = 0;
myArray.splice(0, myArray.length);
```

These will all work.

Answer (score 2):

`myArray.length = 0;` will empty the array.  You can then repopulate it as needed.

Answer (score 1):

If it comes from the database, it would be better to clear your array since some data may be deleted.

To do so, you can write `myArray = [];`